# how to put an array elemnts into a selectable list( like dropdown) in asp.net with C# language

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, arraylist, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an array which contains some elements ( it has created dynamically )
I want to put this array elements into a selectable list/drop down menu so user can select options that i want.
I tried using selec/option method, but i couldnt set the array elements into the option dynamically.
 usingasp.net C#

this is my array:

```
string txt;
txt = Resulttst.Text;
if (txt != "") 
{
    string[] delimiter = { Environment.NewLine };
    string[] ar = txt.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

by the way i can show my array elemnts one by one but i want to put them into a selectable list

here is the code which im using in a test mode in my view page
tell me which part should i change to show the item1, item2, and so on in the drop down list

```
<%   string[] arr = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

 var listItems = arr.Select((r, Index) => new ListItem { Text = r, Value = Index.ToString() });

 DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
 ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray()); %>


 <form runat="server" >
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl"  AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  >
  </asp:DropDownList> </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use DropDownList as this is what you tagged on the question:
For example your have an array name `arr`:

```
        string [] arr = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

        var listItems =  arr.Select((r, Index) => new ListItem { Text = r, Value = Index.ToString() });

        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
since im new to asp.net C# can you please help me more in how to show the drop down list in webform ( aspx page ) too?

the codes that you mentioned are server side codes
i need clientside code as well ( view code)
right now im using the following code in view but the list is empty
     <form id="form9" name="mbrlsttst" runat="server" >
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl"  AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
 </form>

Comment: here is the code which im using in a test mode in my view page
tell me which part should i change to show the item1, item2, and so on in the drop down list

`<%   string[] arr = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

     var listItems = arr.Select((r, Index) => new ListItem { Text = r, Value = Index.ToString() });

     DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
     ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray());
 %>
    
 <form runat="server" >
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl"  AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  >
      </asp:DropDownList>
 </form>`

tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HOKBONG to answer my question

after so many trial/errors, ive found the correct code, which i didnt really need to declare a new dropdownlist anymore, because i've already declared it in view mode
so the behind code is

```
//ar is the array
var listItems = ar.Select((r, Index) => new ListItem { Text = r, Value = Index.ToString() });
ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray());
```

and the view code is:

```
<form runat="server" >
asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="plschs"> -->Please choose a username </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</form>
```

now the above codes work, it calls the array, and insert the values of the array into the dropdownlist